# Serialize and deserialize an IEnumerable in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, serialization, ienumerable

I have this method:

```
public static class SessionExtension
{

    public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }

}
```

Which is useful to serialize my list of IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<FBudget> RecordsList { get; set; }
```

So after filtering the data I serialize the object:

```
//BUILD FILTER
static Expression<Func<FBudget, bool>> BuildFilter(BudgetViewModel budget)
{
    ...
}


 /*STORE THE ACTUAL FILTER IN SESSION*/
 SessionExtension.SetObjectAsJson(HttpContext.Session, "SessionFilter", budget);
```

An the deserialize it:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var json = SessionExtension.GetObjectFromJson<IEnumerable<FBudget>>(HttpContext.Session, "SessionFilter");

        BudgetVM = new BudgetViewModel()
        {
            FBudget = new FBudget(),

            ...

           
            RecordsList = json



    };

        return View(BudgetVM);

    }
```

But when I try to deserialize it, the compiler give the the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[...]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'FBudget', line 1, position 11.'
```

Also I'm trying to do this in order to keep in session the result of the `BuildFilter()` method, so when the user return to a previous page the filters are saved.

Is the correct approach? What am I doing wrong?

This is the Json which is sendend to the method GetObjectFromJson:

```
{"BudgetId":0,"Year":0,"FreeOfCharge":null,"Currency":null,"UnitPrice":0.0,"MonthNr":null,"UnitOfMeasure":null,"Quantity":0,"TotalAmount":0.0,"LastUser":null,"ProgramId":0,"LastUpdate":"2021-11-03T15:08:15.65645+01:00","ItemMasterId":0,"ItemMaster":{"ItemMasterId":0,"ItemNumber":0,"ShortItem":null,"ItemDescription":null,"UnitOfMeasure":null,"FBudgets":null,"PharmaFormId":0,"PharmaForm":null,"ProductGroupId":0,"ProductGroup":null,"UnToBulkId":0,"UnToBulk":null,"UnToKgId":0,"UnToKg":null},"CompanyId":2,"Company":null,"LedgerTypeId":0,"LedgerType":null,"CustomerId":0,"Customer":{"CustomerId":0,"CustomerName":null,"CustomerGroupCode":null,"CountryCode":null,"CustomerGroupName":null,"LicensingArea":null,"FBudgets":null}}
```

Comment: Can you share the sample json which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: From the error message, seems like you try to deserialize a json object {'name': '', 'value': ''}, but it expects a json array like
[
{
'name': '',
'value':''
}
]

Comment: @Chetan done! take a look ( I edited the question)

Comment: @AbuZafor ok, and how do I do that?

Comment: The json you shared does not represent a collection but it is for a single object. Try `SessionExtension.GetObjectFromJson<FBudget>(HttpContext.Session...`

Answer (score 0):

Since your mentioned json is an object not an array, for deserialize try the below code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var json = SessionExtension.GetObjectFromJson<FBudget>(HttpContext.Session, "SessionFilter");

    BudgetVM = new BudgetViewModel()
    {
        FBudget = new FBudget(),
        ...
       
        RecordsList = new List<FBudget> { json }
    };

    return View(BudgetVM);
}
```